# Neo4j: Adding relationships to existing nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I have following nodes and indexes on the unique identifiers:

- Database (databaseName)
- User (username)

and I have a list of users that has access to the databases in a CSV file (one-to-many relationship).

How can I establish a relationship (`HAS_ACCESS_TO`) between User-nodes and database-nodes without being have to specifying the relations one-by-one with Cypher?

Comment: can you give an extract of your csv file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering a CSV file with the following structure:

```
username, databaseName
"user1", "db1"
"user2", "db1"
"user3", "db2"
```

You can use [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/) clause to read the CSV and create the relationships:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///file.csv' AS line
MERGE (u:User {username : line.username})
MERGE (d:Database {databaseName : line.databaseName})
CREATE (u)-[:HAS_ACCESS_TO]->(d)
```

[MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) will create nodes with the specified pattern if it does not exist or use the matching node otherwise.

Comment: I don't think "combine" is the right phrase; perhaps you meant something like "use the matching node(s)"?